# How to display products on sale in one page Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Is that possible to create a page where all products that are on sale will be displayed there?

I try this code but get me all product have sale or no

```
 $args = array(
        'post_type'=>'product',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'showposts' =>$pageSize,
        'paged' => $paged,
        'meta_query' => array(
          array(
              'key' => '_stock_status',
              'value' => 'instock',
              'compare' => '='
          ),
          array(
                    'relation' => 'OR',
                    array(// Simple products type
                        'key' => '_sale_price',
                        'value' => 0,
                        'compare' => '>',
                        'type' => 'numeric'
                    ),
                    array(// Variable products type
                        'key' => '_min_variation_sale_price',
                        'value' => 0,
                        'compare' => '>',
                        'type' => 'numeric'
                    )
                )
        )
    
    );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by default woo-commerce have a option for that use below short code for that:-

```
[products limit="4" columns="4" orderby="popularity" class="quick-sale" on_sale="true" ]
```